# Probability of finding an item

Tags: probability

There are only two stores in Tom's town. Tom wants to buy an item. The probability of finding it in store A is 0.8 and the probability of finding it in store B is 0.6 . What is the probability that Tom will be able to find that item?
My instinct is to add the two probabilities but this of course will be greater than 1. This seems like simple question but I am stumped.

Comment: This question is unanswerable with the information given.  For instance, maybe whenever the item is available in B it's also available in A (they have a common supplier); at the other extreme, maybe both stores watch each other closely and try to keep the item always in stock between the two of them, even when one happens to be out.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense but there were no details. So, assuming the stores operate independently of each other.

Comment: @Sumi if independent, the answer is quite straightforward, as described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Tom stops by all the stores until he finds the item, and the stores are **independent** of each other.

Let's say Tom stops by store A first (without loss of generality, you can do the same with store B, the result is the same). He'll find the item with with probability $0.8$. He won't be able to find it with $0.2$ probability and then he decides to stop by B. In B, there is $0.6$ chance of finding it. So, yielding a total of $0.8+0.2\times 0.6=0.92$ chances of finding the item.

Intuitively, you can think of the situation as follows, where you can understand better why we sum the two: Out of 100 trials, Tom finds the item in store A in 80 of them. On the remaining 20 trials, he'll go to store B. Since there is 60 % of chance that he finds the item, 12 of those visits will end with success, which leaves us with 8 unsuccessful visits in total. So, 92 out of 100 trials will end in success.

Comment: Please see my comment to the question.